# Como enviar um valor preenchido externamente sem o uso de botão

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo um sistema web que lê o serial de um crachá (através de um leitor instalado em um computador) e verifica se essa pessoa tem direito a um bônus cedido caso ela atinja as metas. Estou tentando fazer o sistema verificar de modo automático quando o leitor inserir o serial no campo matrícula porém não estou conseguindo, ele só envia caso o botão seja pressionado.

Tentei os eventos de função do javascript `onChange` e `onBlur`, mas elas não estão sendo chamadas quando o valor é inserido de modo direto pela máquina.

O código com o botão:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="form-rastreio">
    <input type="tel" name="matricula" id="matricula" placeholder="Matrícula" class="form-control" minlength="12" maxlength="12" required>
    <input type="submit" name="botao-retirar" id="botao-retirar" class="btn btn-outline-secondary botao-retirar" value="Retirar rancho">
</form>
```

Como deveria ser sem o botão:

```
<script>
function verifica(){
    console.log("Trocou");
</script>

<form action="index.php" method="post" id="form-rastreio">
    <input type="tel" name="matricula" id="matricula" placeholder="Matrícula" class="form-control" minlength="12" maxlength="12" onchange="verifica()" required>    
</form>
```

Teria algum outro evento que faria isso ou estou usando errado esses eventos?
O serial já vem convertido em um sistema de números de 12 dígitos, por exemplo 000000002953

Comment: Use o [`oninput="..."`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Configure seu leitor para enviar um ENTER no final e use esse form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="form-rastreio">
<input type="tel" name="matricula" id="matricula" placeholder="Matrícula" class="form-control" minlength="1" maxlength="12" required>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).